# What is the point of app directory inside next.js 13?

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I am trying to set up `next-auth` inside next.js 13. In order to be able to use the `useSession` in app directory, I have to convert the page to a client page by using `use client`.

Then I need to wrap `_app.js` with `SessionProvider` and layout file in `app` directory

```
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

and `RootLayout` in `app` component

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
      <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Now I am repeating myself twice and I have to convert server page to a client if I want to use `next-auth`. Is there still any benefit of using `app` directory in this project? In the future, I might have a similar setup for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, I was thinking that the app directory made designing a next.js app more complicated, the difference between client rendering and server rendering performance would not be that big.

Then I realized that this is something related to `scalability`. We could infinitely scale a server but browser resources are limited. We can always add more computing power to servers, however, we can't do that to the client. Since server component bundles stay on the server, if we want to execute our code faster, we just add more computing power to the server